# How to check which rights user has about given repository

Tags: python, git, gitpython

Consider such situations: user clones a repo from an organization `github.com/org/repo`.

Is there a way how info about user's privileges (`read`, `write`, etc.) can be gotten via `gitpython` package?

I'm writing a school app, which will allow automatically `commit` and `push` to repo with one button (but app should show this button only to user's with privileges).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can not. Git permissions are ruled by server, so you can not get these rights locally except by trial and error (which I assume you don't want to do). Also, you can have multiple remotes including local ones.

In the particular case of Github, you can get permissions via [GithubAPI](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/collaborators/)